# I am writing code of following but show blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing code of following but show blank page.

```
var hello = React.createClass({render : function(){return  <div><h1> Hi<h1/</div>;}});React.render(new hello(),document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Hi is undefined
2. React.render accepts a React component, not a new() object
3. Unless you are in older versions of React, you should use ReactDOM to render
4. With React, it is not recommended to render directly to document.body

However this should help you get going:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <p>Hi</p> ;
  }   
});
React.render(<Hello />, document.body);
```